# Why can I assign a QObject* to a QObject?

Tags: c++, qt, explicit-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
#include <QObject>

class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public: 
        A(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
}

int main()
{
    A a = new A();
    return 0;
}
```

Why can I assign an object of type `A*` to a variable of type `A` without the compiler (or runtime) complaining?

Comment: I hope this Q&A-stype question is appropriate here. We recently stumbled upon this behaviour, and had to think about the solution a bit, so I hope it is useful for someone here :-) Sorry if it is not, will delete it otherwise.

Comment: Yes, self-answered questions are perfectly fine (even encouraged), as long as they meet all normal quality expectations. Yours does, as far as I can tell.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code, the constructor of `A` is used to *convert* an `A*` to an object of type `A`, instead of *assigning* it. In general the compiler is allowed to implicitly use a matching constructor as a conversion operator, so that the following is legal code:

```
struct B
{
    B(int i){}
}
int main()
{
    B b = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

In the code of the question, the unnamed `A*` that results from the `new` operator is used as the `parent` argument of the constructor of `A`. This is allowed since `A` is derived from `QObject` (and thus matches the argument list). However, this is clearly undesired behaviour because `a` is not the object returned by `new`, but an object of type `A` parented to that object.
(In addition, the `new`'ed object is never `delete`d, resulting in a memory leak.)

To prevent this kind of subtle error, it is generally advised to make the constructor of `QObject`-derived classes `explicit` to prevent the compiler  from mis-using it as a conversion operator. (This applies to similar situations too, not only to Qt.) 
With the following modified code, the compiler will catch the error:

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public: 
        explicit A(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
}
```